# How to keep the up-to-date value of a variable in a file?

Tags: c++, file, crash

Suppose I have an app A written in C++ that sends messages to app B.
The strict requirement is that B never receives duplicates.
App A reads the messages from a file (1 line per message), and it keeps the line number of last read message in a variable, say, lineNo.
Suppose there's a bug in some other part of app A that causes crash of the whole app A.
On restart, app A should start reading the file not from beginning, but from lineNo. And it should get that lineNo from somewhere.
So, the question is - how can I keep the value of A in a crash-safe way?
My first idea was to write it to a file, but since there's no way (at least known to me) to overwrite a part of a file - I guess I would have to refer to "open file in overwrite mode - write value - close file" for every line I encounter, and that's not a good thing in terms of OS handlers.
Any other options you could think of?

P.S. What I mean by "a bug in some other part" is - it was developed by some other developer that I can't control. Or, for instance - a power went off at the DC. Or a meteorite crashed to it=)
I am actually not only limited to file saving of a variable. Pretty much any technology you can invent - sqlite, memory mapped file - whatever... But I think sqlite is even slower than file access. The memory mapped file is interesting, I'll test it, thank you=)

Comment: "In terms of OS handlers", I see no problem for your file solution. However, the reason for your crash could influence the file writing too (eg. wrong data written, etc.etc. ... just UB).. The proper solution is to fix the bug that causes the crash, nothing else. No workarounds.

Comment: ...and if it is so critical that no message is sent twice, what about a crashing OS, power outage etc.etc.? => Redesign.

Comment: " Suppose there's a bug in some other part of app A that causes crash of the whole app A." Solution: find the bug and fix it. Seriously: any mechanism to make the variable "lineNo" persistent could just introduce new bugs. Its is hard to help unless you are more specific and show some code

Comment: You are asking about a memory mapped file.  What you actually need is pretty unclear.

Comment: Your requirement is flawed, for theoretical reasons. Messages may be lost in transit. You don't know whether the last message you sent has arrived. Even a confirmation message won't resolve this perfectly, because that too may be lost, and you'd then accidentally resend the last message. A robust protocol is necessarily resilient on **both** sides.

Answer (score -1):

> "open file in overwrite mode - write value - close file"

There's no other open mode for files. You can append to files, but that's nothing more than setting the write pointer to the end of the file upon opening.

However, for storage like that, line-oriented files are the wrong format -- things have to be strictly in the same byte position.

Furthermore, there's two things here:

- *B needs a guarantee to never receive duplicates.* Simplest, and most obvious solution: A should never send duplicates by crashing! I may presume that you're not the most experienced programmer, so here's the thing: if you got a requirement like that, you will need to failproof A. Debug it. Why does it crash?
- This sounds like you should be doing proper bidirectional IPC (inter-process communication) between A and B. It would only be normal for A to have a way of asking B what the next value it expects would be.
- depending on your OS, there's a file-like object that is like a pipe, where bytes disappear as soon as they're read: the FIFO. That doesn't work well on Unixoids with crashing consumers, but hey, it's a start.
- There's a lot of IPC frameworks that can build stable pipes, so maybe a file reader-> IPC pipe -> A -> B would be the solution you're after? Have a look at ZeroMQ's REQ/REP sockets.

Comment: Be realistic: crashes are a statistical certainty. Even on redundant hardware, bit error rates are around 1E-15 - 1E-18. Rare, very rare, but they're bound to happen even in programs that are provably correct (!)

Comment: @MSalters: exactly that's why I proposed the "safe" file reader/IPC writer.